# How can I make Notification language the same as phone language

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I need make this code language the same as the device.

```java
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
builder.SetContentTitle("ok");
builder.SetContentText("ok");
Notification nottt = builder.Build();
NotificationManager noeman = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
noeman.Notify (122, nottt);
StopSelfResult(this, OnStartCommand);
```

Comment: Please @joba mark my answer below as correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because you're hardcoding the text that appear in the notification.

Android has a resource file called `strings.xml` in the `/res/values/strings.xml`.

Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose also that you want to localize all the text in your application to Portuguese.
In this case, you could create two alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:

Directory:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string
            name="string_name">nome</string>
    </resources>
```

Contains English (default in this case) text for all the strings that the application uses.

Directory:

```
res/values-pt/strings.xml
```

File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="string_name">nome</string>
</resources>
```

Contain Portuguese text for all the strings.

After creating the string files you should build your notification using the resources like this:

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.string_name))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.other_string));
```

For more information click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use (string resource) by 'alt+enter' on your string "ok" and select (Extract String Resource),
and then use (getApplicationContext())

```
builder.SetContentTitle(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.ok));
builder.SetContentText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.ok));
```